# Performance between consuming a Webservice inside of a same website through WebReference or through instantiation

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, web-services

Look I'm concerning about what is faster/best about consuming a WebService who is within the same WebSite/WebApplication.

Imagine I have a 20 pages and 1 WebService in the same WebSite..

In each page I have to consume everything from the WebService...

But my concern is how it should be consumed? I should add the webreference of my WebService who is in the same website and use everything with the proxy generation of that Webservice.. or I should instantiate directly the WebService like a normal Class and consume the methods?

I know (or I think) that the best practice is to consume it like a webService for the SOA especifications and have the WebService in another website in my solution.

But my reasoning says that consuming a WebService needs http protocols who makes a request through this protocol, and a webservice serialize the response...

An important thing to remark I guess, is that the webmethods of My WebService can return several records /information /data, so the serialization step could be a problem or a performance issue.

I'm looking for the best way of doing this.

Should I move the WebService to another Site and consume it in my pages? even though the performance will be affected? or I should not? if yes, how much? it will cost ? or the impact is not significant?

If I should move the WebService does it affect if I consume it like http:// localhost .. instead of ... 192.168.1.1, or a web domain than localhost? is it the same or does it affect in something?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But my reasoning says that consuming a WebService needs http protocols
>   who makes a request through this protocol, and a webservice serialize
>   the response...

Your reasoning is absolutely correct. If you are inside the same project there's no need to waste CPU cycles in useless HTTP requests. You could directly invoke the same repository layer that your web service methods already uses. You could still expose the web service using an interoperable format (such as SOAP) if you need non .NET clients to consume it, otherwise I don't think it's really necessary. Actually why did you develop a web service on the first place? I guess you had some expectations about future consumers? The rule of thumb is to always encapsulate a reusable service domain logic into a service layer and then depending on who needs to consume it, either directly use the assembly in which you implemented this functionality (if we are talking about .NET clients) or if you need interoperability, it's pretty trivial to use WCF to expose this service layer using interoprable protocols.

But if you are interested in the exact figures, don't hesitate to perform some load tests and compare the response times between a direct .NET method call directly from within your cinsuming web application and an HTTP request using an interoperable protocol.

Remark: WebReference clients are deprecated now. You should use a ServiceReference instead if you decide to invoke your service throughout a network connection.

Comment: does it affect if I consume it like http://localhost .. instead of ... http://www.google.com .. an Ip, a domain than localhost? is it the same or does it affect in something?

Comment: If you consume as a .NET client, you directly use the service layer that your web service already uses. There's no HTTP request. There's no `localhost`. There's no `google.com`. There's a .NET method call at the IL level.

Comment: Thanks! But I think it should be a difference. I think... imagine I got not Internet in that moment, if I try to consume my webservice with the endpoint 74.125.227.112 (Google's IP) I think in somepoint c# will try to find it by Internet.. and it would fail.. or if I use the endpoint as www.google.com it would fail again, but if i set the endpoint as localhost it should work, that's my guessing, but I know nothing about that protocols, Am i wrong? excuse my ignorance

Comment: We are comparing here a direct .NET method call in contrast to consuming a web service throughout an HTTP request. The first will be much faster. The second depends on your network configuration.

Comment: BTW I didn't develop it, in fact It has consumers, that's why it has to be a webservice (Framework 2.0 here) that's why I can't use a WCF

Comment: Yes indeed, if your client is .NET 2.0 and the service is WCF (a.k.a .NET 3.0+) you actually have no choice but to use a WebReference. You can't even directly use the assembly to invoke the method if you don't have .NET 3.0 installed on the client.

Comment: thanks for that information, didn't know about it, Do you recommend me ? If I upgrade to 3.5 my project, move my WebService to another site/layer to have the separed Pages and the Webservices,and add the new website as an assembly to my currently website it would be the best in SOA practices and performance? (Thanks for all your help)

Comment: Upgrading your client application to .NET 3.5+ would indeed be a good thing. Then in terms of performance would be to directly reference the assembly and invoke the methods, and in terms of SOA the best would be to use a ServiceReference and consume your WCF service using an HTTP request. There are different approaches that will depend on your scenario and requirements. Don't ask which is the best because each one has its pros and cons. Everything will depend on what you are trying to achieve and your precise requirements. In some cases direct method call is better in other service reference.